# JavaScript , ajax call to webfunction(vb) wont return success or error

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

This is my js. It is triggered by a button click and then calls for a web function.
The webfunction works correctly with no errors, but on the js noone of the .done or success or error prompts appear so i cannot debug why in the end it doesnt call the webfunction at all.

function updateTicket(TicketID) {

```
var strActualEffort = document.getElementById("txtActualEffort").value;
var fltActualEffort;

fltActualEffort = parseFloat(strActualEffort);

if (!isNaN(fltActualEffort)) {
    CalculateRisk(fltActualEffort);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "web function url",
        data: { ID: TicketID, Effort: fltActualEffort },
        success: function OnSuccess(e) { alert('SUCCESS!' + e); },
        error: function OnError(e) { alert('Failed coz : ' + e); },
        complete: function OnComplete() { alert('COMPLETE'); }
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert("success" + data.slice(0, 100));
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    }).always(function () {
        alert("complete");
    }); 
}
```

}

any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your web function code, it seems like it isn't returning anything so your ajax is waiting indefinitely

Comment: even when i had the web function as empty with nothing inside it did the same thing. the webfunction just calls for an sql and on its own when i went to the ..asmx file the code runs correctly so for sure its not a problem with the function

Comment: Yes but does it run the code AND write a response? If you don't have it sending anything back then the ajax never receives anything.

Comment: no it was a sub.. so it needs a return to get either of those alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues Fixed.

The ajax wasnt doing anything because using IE the window closed before the actual web method was called.

Solved it by setting the ajax function call as asynch.